# How to show iPhone size views on iPad applications

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an iPhone application (app1) which has to be integrated as a sub-application on another universal iOS app (app2).

For various reasons I don't want to create an iPad interface for my iPhone app1, I just want that all the views will be shown with iPhone dimensions (at the center of the screen) also when the main app2 is executed on an iPad. On app1 I do not support landscape orientation, only portrait.

Is this somehow possible to realize?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code!

```
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:yourViewController];
[popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
```

And to show the popoverController in the middle of the iPad screen

```
UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];    
if(thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(380, 450, 1, 1) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
}
```

To maintain always the same size of your UIPopoverController do not forget to set the contentSizeForViewInPopover in each view (do this inside the viewWillAppear:)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[self setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 480)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can do this. Assuming you have built your original application using UIViewControllers, the iPad has a special kind of class called a [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) where you can spawn a UIViewController onto the screen of the iPad at a given size.

To embed an iPhone app in a iPad app, set the root UIViewController of your iPhone App to the View Controller in the Popover Controller, set the size of the popover to 320x640 and spawn it by calling the presentPopover function.

I hope this helps!
N

Comment: Ahha! Glad I was able to help!! :)